# Extract a substring in C

Tags: c, linux

i am trying to extract the username from this uri field in ANSI C code on linux using gcc

```
mail:username@example.com
```

so i need to strip the mail: and everything after the @. Are there any built in functions in C to extract substrings

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
char *uri_field = "mail:username@example.com";

char username[64];

sscanf(uri_field, "mail:%63[^@]", username);
```

If you might have other "junk" at the beginning (not necessarily just `mail:`), you could do something like this instead:

```
sscanf(uri_field, "%*[^:]:%63[^@]", username);
```

Comment: did not know you could do this with scanf, very nice :)

Comment: @Matt: it is pretty cool, isn't it? The single thing I miss the most when I use C++ iostreams is anything equivalent to scanf's `%[whatever]` and `%[^whatever]`.

Comment: better is if( 1==sscanf(uri_field, "mail:%63[^@]", username) ), isnt it?

Comment: @gordongekko: yes, you usually want to check for errors (especially when you're dealing with user input), though unless that's the subject at hand, I usually leave (most) error checking out of answers like this for the sake of clarity.

Comment: @JerryCoffin : I'm having trouble for getting the firs nameserver in /etc/resolv.conf using a single fscanf. I've tried `fscanf(fp,"%*nameserver:%20[^\n]",address);` which return 0 (no result founds); And `address` is empty. (Yes the file as been successfully opened before with fopen).

Comment: @user2284570: your format string doesn't make sense. Given the normal format of a /etc/resolv.conf file, you want something like: `fscanf(fp, "nameserver %20[^\n]", address);`

Comment: @JerryCoffin : It work only in some rare case (It is the first thing I tried) because resolv.conf often don't begin with `nameserver` at the start of the file. Most of the time the file start with comments («# Generated by NetworkManager») or other parameters like `domains` or `search`.

Comment: @user2284570: Yes--for such a situation you'll typically need/want to read a line, attempt to scan it as the type of line you care about, check the return from sscanf to see if that succeeded, and just ignore the line and move on to the next if it didn't succeed.

Comment: @JerryCoffin. I don't want to copy the file into a buffer (that's why I want to use a single fscanf for getting the result directly, and not srtok). I just need a single nameserver. I need the exact "regex" (I know it is not really regex) which would mean everything with an unknow content length until "nameserver". because `%*`don't seems to be the right solution, or there is a mistake in my expression.

Comment: @user2284570: I don't think it can be done with a single fscanf format string. Problem is that (for example) a line starting with `#` has to be skipped completely--it could contain an invalid `nameserver`. Given line-oriented comments, you pretty much need to read a line, then ignore it if it's a comment.

Comment: @JerryCoffin : In my case, the resolv.conf is always generated by a third party application. So I know a line will never be commented out. (my application will run locally and won't be public). So do you have any ideas for the "regex"? please...

Comment: @user2284570: If you have (for example) 3 comment lines followed by a `nameserver` line, you could use something like: `fscanf(in, "%*[^\n] %*[^\n] %*[^\n] nameserver %20[^\n]", address);`

Comment: @JerryCoffin : let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48621/discussion-between-user2284570-and-jerry-coffin)

Answer (score 3):

You could use also `strtok`. Look at this example

```
/* strtok example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

    int main ()
    {
      char str[] ="mail:username@example.com";
      char * pch;
      pch = strtok (str," :@");
      while (pch != NULL)
      {
        printf ("%s\n",pch);
        pch = strtok (NULL, " :@");
      }
      return 0;
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
void getEmailName(const char *email, char **name /* out */) {
    if (!name) {
        return;
    }

    const char *emailName = strchr(email, ':');

    if (emailName) {
        ++emailName;
    } else {
        emailName = email;
    }

    char *emailNameCopy = strdup(emailName);

    if (!emailNameCopy) {
        *name = NULL;

        return;
    }

    char *atSign = strchr(emailNameCopy, '@');

    if (atSign) {
        *atSign = '\0'; // To remove the '@'
        // atSign[1] = '\0';  // To keep the '@'
    }

    if (*name) {
        strcpy(*name, emailNameCopy);
    } else {
        *name = emailNameCopy;
    }
}
```

This creates a pointer to the `:` character (`colon`) within the string.  (It does not make a copy of the string.)  If the `:` is found, point to the character after it.  If the `:` doesn't exist, just use the beginning of the string (i.e. assume no `mail:` prefix).

Now we want to strip everything from the `@` onward, so we make a copy of the string (`emailNameCopy`) and later cut off the `@`.

The code then creates a pointer to the `@` character (atSign) within the string.  If the `@` character exists (i.e. strchr returns non-NULL), the character at the `@` is set to zero, marking the end of the string.  (A new copy isn't made.)

We then return the string, or copy it if a buffer was given.

Comment: Note this is C99.  I'm not sure if `strdup` is standard (I was always confused about that bit), but reading man should tell you what it does and it's easy to reproduce in a few lines of code.

Comment: just FWIW, no `strdup` is not standard (though it is pretty common). Officially, the name is reserved so if you write one yourself, you get undefined behavior. Anybody who's really bothered by that can just use another name that doesn't start with `str`.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, which does not rely in any special possibility, and is easily capable of detecting errors is the following one. Note that you'll have to free the string when the function extractUsername() succeeds.

Note that in C you just navigate in a sequence of chars, using pointer arithmetic. There are a few standard library functions, but they are much more simpler than anything able to extract information from the string.

There are still other issues for error detection, such as the presence of more than one '@', for example. But this should be enough as a starting point.

```
// Extract "mail:username@example.com"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

const char * MailPrefix = "mail:";
const char AtSign = '@';

char * extractUserName(const char * eMail)
{
    int length = strlen( eMail );
    char * posAtSign = strrchr( eMail, AtSign );
    int prefixLength = strlen( MailPrefix );

    char * toret = (char *) malloc( length + 1 );
    if ( toret != NULL
      && posAtSign != NULL
      && strncmp( eMail, MailPrefix, prefixLength ) == 0 )
    {
        memset( toret, 0, length  +1 );
        strncpy( toret, eMail + prefixLength, posAtSign - prefixLength - eMail );
    }
    else {
        free( toret );
        toret = NULL;
    }

    return toret;
}

int main()
{
    const char * test = "mail:baltasarq@gmail.com";

    char * userName = extractUserName( test );

    if ( userName != NULL ) {
        printf( "User name: '%s'\n", userName );
        free( userName );
    } else {
        fprintf( stderr, "Error: invalid e.mail address\n" );
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```