# Regex to extract specific substring from string

Tags: c, regex, string

I am trying to extract a substring from string in c. I was trying to copy [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3478682/985012) answer but I can't get the regex right.

From the string

`"-u username@web.com -p password -P passphrase -t tun_dev0 www.google.ie"`

I would like to extract `tun_dev0`. Also, the parameters in that string may be in any order and there may be a variable number of spaces after the `-t`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    char *parameters = "-u username@web.com -p password -P passphrase -t tun_dev0 www.google.ie";

    char tun[64];

    sscanf(parameters, "-t %63[^ *]", tun);

    fprintf(stderr, "\n%s\n\n",tun);

    return 0;
}
```

Note: The string is not the parameters provided to this program

**Edit**

As per perreal's answer, here is my implementation, it appears to work but it seems to skip the first parameter.

```
/*Get the parameter value associated with the specified parameter i.e -t / -p */
char *get_parameter(char *parameters, char parameter)
{
    char *p = strtok(parameters, "-");
    while(p) {
        p = strtok(NULL, "-");
        if (NULL != p) {
            if (p[0] == parameter) {
                p = strtok(p, " ");
                p = strtok(NULL, " ");
                printf("%s\n", p); 
                return p;
                break;
            }
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    char parameters[100] = "-u username@web.com -p password -P passphrase -t tun_dev0 www.google.ie";
    char *parameter_value;

    parameter_value = get_parameter(parameters,'u');

    if (parameter_value != NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"%s\n",parameter_value);
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr,"No matching param found!\n");
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is a subtle issue concerning `char *parameters = "-u us..."`.  Suggest OP real wants `char parameters[] = "-u us..."`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use strtok:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
    char parameters[] = "-u username@web.com -p password -P passphrase -t tun_dev0 www.google.ie";
    char *t = strtok(parameters, "-");
    while(t) {
        t = strtok(NULL, "-");
        if (t[0] == 't') {
            t = strtok(t, " ");
            t = strtok(NULL, " ");
            printf("%s\n", t); 
            break;
        }
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

You with `strtok` you can't parse nested options. But you can first get the `-` arguments and process them:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char parameters[] = "-u username@web.com -p password -P passphrase -t tun_dev0 www.google.ie";
    char *t; 
    char *args[256] = {0}, **arg = args;
    for (t = strtok(parameters, "-"); t != NULL; t = strtok(NULL, "-"), arg++) {
        *arg = t;  
    }   
    for (arg = args; *arg; arg++) {
        for (t = strtok(*arg, " "); t != NULL; t = strtok(NULL, " ")) {
            printf("%s\n", t); 
        }
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Actually there is one problem with this, it appears to skip the first parameter, any idea how to fix that?

Comment: @Tomcelic, you mean the `-u`?

Answer (score 0):

`strtok()` is the better way, but if you *still* want `sscanf()`,

```
char tun[64];
const char *p = parameters;
while (*p) {
  if (1 == sscanf(p, "-t %63s", tun)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "\n%s\n\n",tun);
    break;
  }
  p++;
}
```